# How to get server side of Java socket to return 404 error when file not found?

Tags: java, http, http-status-code-404, serversocket

I am taking a networking module at university and am beginning Java socket programming. I have the server code written at the end of this post, which accepts client requests and sends text from a file called data.txt (a simple hello world type message). That all works fine.

I now want to modify the server to accept the file name at the command line and if the file is not found (i.e. what's entered in the command line is not "data.txt."), to return a 404 error. I have modified the constructor as you can see but it still returns the data. I'm not really sure how a http header features in all this to be honest and don't know where to go from here.

```
//
// Web8000.java an HTTP Web server from Elliotte Rusty Harold.
// Listens on a socket waiting for a client to send a GET request.
// Always responds with the contents of a fixed text file!
//

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Web8000 extends Thread {

    private byte[] header;  // the message header
    private byte[] content; // the message content

    private final static int DEFAULT_PORT = 8000;   // the default listening port
    private int port = DEFAULT_PORT;

    public Web8000(boolean fileFound, byte[] data, String encoding, String MIMEtype, int port) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        content = data;         // set up the message content
        this.port = port;   // use the port number passed

        if (fileFound) {
            String header = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                    + "Server: Web8000 1.0\r\n"
                    + "Content-length: " + content.length + "\r\n"
                    + "Content-type: " + MIMEtype + "\r\n\r\n";
            this.header = header.getBytes("ASCII"); // assume ASCII encoding system
        } 
        else {
            String header = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n"
                    + "Server: Web8000 1.0\r\n"
                    + "Content-length: " + content.length + "\r\n"
                    + "Content-type: " + MIMEtype + "\r\n\r\n";
            this.header = header.getBytes("ASCII"); // assume ASCII encoding system
        }

    }

    // enable thread to deal with client
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);
            // log details of server response on screen
            System.out.println("Connecting on port: " + serverSock.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println("Data to be sent: ");
            System.out.write(content);

            while (true) {  // loop forever dealing with clients
                Socket clientSock = null;
                try {
                    clientSock = serverSock.accept();   // get skt for client-server comms
                    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());

                    // read request and assume buffer big enough!
                    StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer(800);
                    int ch = 0;
                    Boolean finished = false; // so we can read bytes until all of hdr.

                    while (!finished) {
                        ch = in.read(); // read next char (byte), actually returns int!
                        if (ch == -1) { // did sender somehow fail during transmission?
                            System.out.println("Sender died?");
                            finished = true;
                        } else {    //append the char to the string buffer
                            System.out.print((char) ch);
                            request.append((char) ch);
                            if (ch == '\n') {   //see if end of header
                                if (request.toString().indexOf("\r\n\r\n") != -1) {
                                    finished = true;    //what if "\r\r" or "\n\n"?
                                }
                            }
                        }   //deal with bytes recvd
                    }   //while more bytes to read

                    //check that it is an HTTP request. Should check for GET etc too!
                    if (request.toString().indexOf("HTTP/") != -1) {
                        out.write(header);  //okay so write MIMEtype hdr details
                    }                   //now send the actual data content
                    out.write(content);
                    out.flush();    //to make sure the buffer is emptied immediately
                } //try
                catch (IOException ioE) {
                } finally { //make sure this end of the connection gets closed
                    if (clientSock != null) {
                        clientSock.close();
                    }
                }
            }   //while forever
        } //try opening server socket
        catch (IOException ioE) {
            System.err.println("Could not start server. Port in use!");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String fileName = /*(args[0])*/ "data.txt"; // user provides file name
            String contentType = "text/html";
            boolean fileFound = false;

            if ("data.txt".equals(fileName)) fileFound = true;

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Adam Matheson\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\scratch\\src\\resource\\data.txt");    // open specified file
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int bite;
            while ((bite = in.read()) != -1) // Now read bytes from file ...
            {
                out.write(bite);    // ...into byte stream
            }
            byte[] data = out.toByteArray(); // convert byte stream into an array of bytes ready for DatagramPacket

            int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
            String encoding = "ASCII";

            //create the thread to send the contents of the file to any connection!
            Thread thr = new Web8000(fileFound, data, encoding, contentType, port);
            thr.start();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException obE) {
            //useful for when args should have been supplied!
            System.err.println("Usage: java Web8000 filename port encoding");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```